# Next.JS component breaking after reload & state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on a Next.JS project however came across an issue I have not been able to resolve.

Whenever I reload the page, one of the components renders, more or less, as child of itself. Here is an video of what happens:
[image]

Here follows the code relevant:

```html
          <Col md={9} className={styles.Main}>
            {roomsError && <p>{t('common:DATA_LOADING_ERROR_TEXT')}</p>}
            {roomsData.length > 0 && <RoomCards user={user} roomsData={roomsData} />}
            {roomsData.length === 0 && !loading && <RoomCardEmpty/>}
            {loading && <p>{t('ROOMS_LOADING_ROOMS')}</p>}
          </Col>
```

```js
const [roomsData, setRoomsData] = useSessionStorage('dorms', []);
const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const [roomsError, setRoomsError] = useState(false);
```

```scss
.Main {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```js
export default function RoomCards({
  roomsData = [],
  user = null,
  uploadsPage = false,
  className = '',
  style,
  ...restProps
}) {
  const {t} = useTranslation('rooms');
  const rowClassName = uploadsPage ? 'row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2' : '';

  const colMd = uploadsPage ? null : 10;

  if (roomsData.length === 0) {
    return (
      <>
        {uploadsPage && <p>{t('ROOMS_CARDS_NO_UPLOADED_ROOMS_TEXT')}</p>}
        {!uploadsPage && <p>{t('ROOMS_CARDS_NO_ROOMS_TEXT')}</p>}
      </>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <Row className={`justify-content-center g-5 ${rowClassName}`} style={uploadsPage ? {paddingBottom: '80px'} : {}}>
        {roomsData.map((roomData, index) => (
          <Col
            key={index}
            md={colMd}
            className={className}
            style={style}
            {...restProps}
          >
            {roomData.external ?
                <ExternalRoomCard
                  user={user}
                  roomData={roomData}
                  uploadsPage={uploadsPage}
                /> :
                <RoomCard
                  user={user}
                  roomData={roomData}
                  uploadsPage={uploadsPage}
                />}
          </Col>
        ))}
      </Row>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the rendered HTML:

*Before Reload*:

[image]

*After Reload*:

[image]

I hope anyone can tell me what goes wrong here and can help me to resolve this.

EDIT:
Another attempt... Weird behavior...
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there a console warning/error about the hydration error being displayed? I see your `roomsData` depends on the session storage, which is unavailable on the server-side (fallbacks to an empty array) and then populated on the front-end side, which may create a conflict.

Comment: Hi, there is no warning regarding that. I've added a new screenshot with another attempt and some additional logs which may tell more.

Comment: Now, look into the Next.JS console. Do you see the 'yes false' logs?

Comment: It gives the false logs there yes, however the states are changed in useEffect

Comment: Could you provide the source code of `useSessionStorage`?